# Getting the filename through Carrierwave in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

*I was hoping I could get some insight on how to retrieve the file name submitted in order to read the file into a temp variable and do processing on it.*

I have been trying to incorporate carrierwave's gem into a project I'm working on that deals with parsing in text and formatting it.  I have my code working for input that is copied into a text field that I have made but can't seem to incorporate text submitted as a file.
The relevant portion of my model is below:

```
class JDatum < ActiveRecord::Base
mount_uploader :text, TextUploader
after_validation  :setoutput



private 

def setoutput
    if self.jInput.size == 0
        dir = self.text.file.filename
        contents = dir.to_s.read
        parsed = JSON.parse(contents)
        self.jOutput = init_parse(parsed)
    else parsed = JSON.parse(self.jInput) 
        self.jOutput = init_parse(parsed)
    end
end
```

I have tried multiple ways posted to try and get the file name after they submit but most result in either it saying that text is nil, or that the method doesn't exist for nil class.

**undefined method `filename' for nil:NilClass**

I pretty much just followed the railscast tutorial for submitting and putting pictures with the difference that I was interested in text files instead.

Below is the view where I would show the output jOutput would still be called that regardless of type of input as shown in model where I assign jOutput to either the input that went into text file or uploaded file.

```
<p>
  <center><h1 style = "color:#000">Formatted Output</h1></center>
  <strong style = "color:#333"><%= simple_format(@j_datum.jOutput) %></strong>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_j_datum_path(@j_datum) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', j_data_path %>
```

And here is the view where the input is done where the f.file_field :text is the upload button on the form.

```
<%= form_for @j_datum do |f| %>
  <% if @j_datum.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@j_datum.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this j_datum from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @j_datum.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <center><div class="field">
    <%= f.label :jInput %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :jInput ,:cols => 100, :rows => 25%>
  </div></center>
  <p> 
    <%= f.file_field :text %>
  </p>
  <center><div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div></center>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you share the view from where you are trying to upload the text file? You question seems confusing.

Comment: @KirtiThorat There I edited the question including the view. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your form_for :

```
 :html => { :multipart => true }
```

For example:

```
<%= form_for @j_datum, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
```

Comment: I added that and re ran the server but it still gives me an error on this line "dir = self.text.file.filename".  What I did notice that is strange is that even though I'm calling text.file.filename it says NoMethodError in JDataController#create and undefined method `filename' for nil:NilClass.  So what I don't understand is why it's trying to access the filename method through my controller instead of the uploader model.

Comment: You are uploading a file when you try this, rt? Setoutput is an after_validation, while creating/ updating a record of your model, it will be called.

Comment: yeah this is what is displayed after I select the file and then click my submit button.